# explode multi-dimentional array stored in mssql as multiple rows

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I am trying to get meetings scheduled tomorrow and get the users id from the row which is saved in ms sql table as comma separated values, using the id i have to get their contact number from another table i tried something like this here i can get the value of first array only i know i made something wrong here but i don't know where

```
    $date=date("d-m-Y", time()+86400);
    $start_time=strtotime($date.", 12:01 AM");
    $end_time=strtotime($date.", 11:59 PM");
    $sql=$db->Query("select * from pp_meeting where m_date > ? and m_date < ?", array($start_time, $end_time));

    while($row=$db->FetchRow($sql)){
        $users[]=explode(",", $row['m_users']);
        foreach($users as $us){
                foreach($us as $u){
                $sql=$db->Query("select contact_no from pp_users where user_id=?", array($u));
                echo $result=$db->FetchOne($sql);echo "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
```

thank you

Comment: dont have the mysql query in a loop.It will create a requests each time and take much time.Use IN query

Comment: @user3040610 thank you for your solution, if i place foreach outside while loop it works fine.

Comment: ,if the comments helped you, pls vote it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 1 nested query instead of looping query

```
"select contact_no from pp_users where user_id in  
(select user_id from pp_meeting where m_date > ? and m_date < ?)"
```

or you can use join

```
"select contact_no  
from pp_users join pp_meeting on user_id=user_id  
where m_date > ? and m_date < ?"
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, if i place foreach outside while loop it works fine